# Windows XP cannot join (samba) domain

Tags: windows-xp, samba, ubuntu-10.04, domain-controller

I've a setup with Samba 3.4.7 on Ubuntu 10.04 running as Primary Domain Controller for the network.

[Almost] everything works fine, except for a single Windows XP computer which cannot join the domain. All the other computers, either XP or 7, can correctly join and authenticate, change password and whatever else.

The error returned by WinXP is

> 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR [...] executed query _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.MYDOMAINNAME

So I add this specific DNS query to the dns server to return FILE-SERVER, on the next try:

> The query identified "FILE-SERVER" as domain controller. Most common causes: missing A record or Domain Controllers are not connected

Obviously none of the two apply.

I tried all three *netsh* commands suggested, I ran *sfc /scannow*, all without success. 
I really don't know what else to look for. Any suggestion would really be appreciated.

Comment: what's on the workstation's netsetup.log?

Comment: 0x54b is the returned value for the check.
On a side note I just checked the DHCP log, the client issues a DHCP refresh every two minutes while the dhcp lease time is 12h!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961817.aspx table 10.6, it cannot find your dc.

Comment: thanks but nltest doesn't work and netdiag doesn't return any error.
What about the DHCP issue?

Comment: sorry, I did not mean to imply the technet link was the solution, I simply pointed to the problem. It cannot find the domain controller (problably missing srv records). As it is a samba pdc and not AD or samba 4, I am not going to be able to help you any further. The samba list could be of assistance, though.